Selection pool not available after page migration
We migrated a Sitecore Content Hub page(containing Creation,Selection and Search component) across the environments from Import/Export feature. Same way we migrated corresponding selection pool as well from entities.
But on the destination environment page displays along with the components but selection pool is not getting populated (the dropdown is empty).
Required selection pool do exists in this environment we can get the result using api (
/api/entities/identifier/xaaLwJqHQQG_jXRqYuzdfd3Q)
Is there anything else we need to migrate for the selection pool to be available in the destination environment? Or any other settings we need check.
Thanks
Shrutika
